# GitHub workflow of opening consecutive PRs

Tags: git, github

I'm contributing to a repo whose owner is not very responsive. I want to develop a new feature, but first I need to refactor some functions (will be used to create the new feature).

I've opened a PR for the refactoring (still waiting to be merged). The refactoring is already big enough for a single PR. So now I want to open another PR for the new feature. I could open a new one with all the commits from the previous PR plus the commits for the new feature. But I'm wondering is there a better way to do this.

Or should I wait for the previous PR to be merged before I open a new one?

Comment: Not really relevant to StackOverflow.

Comment: Then where should I ask about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that new feature depends on your refactoring, you can open that PR right away, but:

- that new feature branch must start from your current refectoring branch
- that new feature PR must include in its comment that it depends on PR xxx (the refactoring PR) to be merged first
- if the refactoring PR has to be updated in any way (new commits, rebase, ...), you will have to rebase your new feature branch on top of the updated refactoring branch and force push.

Comment: That's basically how I did this before, :) just that I commented in the PR instead to tell the owner to merge the other one first. Again, is there a better way to do this? Or that's exactly what you would do if you were in my position?

Comment: @damonh No: GitHub does not support dependencies between PR, so for now, a comment is best.